# How can I change this code from O(n^2) to O(n) time complexity as it is exceeding the required time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

```
class Solution {
    public int maxArea(int[] height) {

        int area=0;
        for(int i=0;i<(height.length-1);i++)
        {
            
            for(int j=height.length-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                int breath=j-i;
                int heig=(int)Math.min(height[i],height[j]);
                int are=breath*heig;

                if(are>area)
                   area=are;
            }
        }
        return area;
    }
}
```

I tried doing it this way but its not working.The time limit gets exceeded at 55th test case.It is a question for array on leetcode.

https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/

Comment: with a single loop maintain 2 pointers

Comment: with nested array you can not achieve o(n) time complexity

Answer (score 1):

You don't solve these things by taking the naive solution and magically optimizing it. You solve them by thinking about the problem and reasoning out what the non-naive solution is.

In this case, if you start with the two bounding height indices, call them `left` and `right`, and iterate by incrementing `left` if `height[left] < height[right]` and decrementing `right` otherwise, the area contained by [`left`,`right`] is guaranteed to be the maximum at some point.

To see this, note that the horizontal space between `left` and `right` only ever gets smaller. If at some point we are not at the maximum area configuration the only way we can possibly get there is by choosing to move the side of the range that has lower height, and since at all times the maximum area range is either the current range or within the current range doing so eventually finds the solution or we have already found the solution.

C++ code below:

```
int maxArea(const std::vector<int>& height) {
    int max_area = -1;
    int left = 0;
    int right = static_cast<int>(height.size() - 1);
    while (left < right) {
        int area = (right - left) * std::min(height[left], height[right]);
        max_area = (area > max_area) ? area : max_area;

        if (height[left] < height[right]) {
            ++left;
        } else {
            --right;
        }
    }
    return max_area;
}
```